# MemSQL Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark, singlestore

I am trying to read a CSV file in Spark job using MemSQL Extractor and do some enrichment using Transformer and load to MemSQL Database using Java.

I see there is memsql-spark interface jar but not finding any useful Java API documentation or example.

I have started writing extractor to read from CSV but I dont know how to move further.

```
public Option<RDD<byte[]>> nextRDD(SparkContext sparkContext, UserExtractConfig config, long batchInterval, PhaseLogger logger) {
        RDD<String> inputFile = sparkContext.textFile(filePath, minPartitions);
    RDD<String> inputFile = sparkContext.textFile(filePath, minPartitions);

    RDD<byte[]> bytes = inputFile.map(ByteUtils.utf8StringToBytes(filePath), String.class); //compilation error

    return bytes; //compilation error

}
```

Would appreciate if someone can point me to some direction to get started...

thanks...

Comment: Have you checked out the examples repo? https://github.com/memsql/streamliner-examples/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/memsql/streamliner/examples

Comment: I looked at example, but its in scala and I am not much familiar with it.
If you can make me understand how to construct nextRDD() method it would be great. Updating my orginal post of the code I have written so far...

Comment: Getting compilation error at two lines...can you point what is wrong?

Comment: Hey, right now it is not recommended to write Java Spark jobs as the Java interface is much less mature than the Scala interface.  Is it possible for you to write your pipeline using our streamliner-start repo as pointed out by eklhad?  If not, something like this should help you out:  https://gist.github.com/carlsverre/ebbfcd3562a0aba8a3b0

Answer (score 0):

First configure Spark connector in java using following code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.set("spark.datasource.singlestore.clientEndpoint", "singlestore-host")
spark.conf.set("spark.datasource.singlestore.user", "admin")
spark.conf.set("spark.datasource.singlestore.password", "s3cur3-pa$$word")
```

After running the above code spark will be connected to java then you can read csv in spark dataframe. You can transform and manipulate data according to requirements then you can write this dataframe to Database table.

Also attaching link for your reference.
[spark-singlestore](https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.8/en/load-data/load-data-from-a-data-source/load-data-from-spark/examples.html?action=version-change).